# RVM Debug output on terminal

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, installation, rvm

I'm seeing this every time I open terminal, after a RVM installation:

```
Last login: Tue Dec  2 10:35:44 on ttys000
rvm_debug () {
    (( ${rvm_debug_flag:-0} )) || return 0
    if rvm_pretty_print stderr
    then
        printf "%b" "${rvm_debug_clr:-}$*${rvm_reset_clr:-}\n"
    else
        printf "%b" "$*\n"
    fi >&2
}
```

This is my bash_profile:

```
[10:54:13] old_ian :: Ians-MacBook-Pro-2  ➜  ~ ⭑  cat .bash_profile
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/etc/cacert.pem
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

### RVM
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

alias bex="bundle exec"
alias grep="grep --color=auto"
alias vi=vim
alias postgres="pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log"
[10:54:19] old_ian :: Ians-MacBook-Pro-2  ➜  ~ ⭑
```

Maybe something went wrong with it's install ?
I've been using it with no problems.

UPDATES:
Posting cat RVM

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# rvm : Ruby enVironment Manager
# https://rvm.io
# https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm

# partial duplication marker dkjnkjvnckbjncvbkjnvkj
# prevent from loading in sh shells
if
  \command \test -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}"
then
  case "`uname`" in
    (CYGWIN*) __shell_name="`\command \ps -p $$ | \command \awk 'END {print $NF}'` 2>/dev/null" ;;
    (*)       __shell_name="`\command \ps -p $$ -o comm=`"                ;;
  esac
  case "$__shell_name" in
    (""|dash|sh|*/dash|*/sh) return 0 ;; # silently stop in sh shells
  esac
  unset __shell_name
else
  return 0
fi

# also duplicated in scripts/base
__rvm_has_opt()
{
  {
    # pre-gnu
    [[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION}"  ]] && setopt | GREP_OPTIONS="" \command \grep "^${1}$" >/dev/null 2>&1
  } ||
  {
    [[ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]] && [[ ":$SHELLOPTS:" =~ ":${1}:" ]]
  } ||
  return 1
}

# Do not allow sourcing RVM in `sh` - it's not supported
# return 0 to exit from sourcing this script without breaking sh
if __rvm_has_opt "posix"
then return 0
fi

# TODO: Alter the variable names to make sense
\export HOME rvm_prefix rvm_user_install_flag rvm_path
HOME="${HOME%%+(\/)}" # Remove trailing slashes if they exist on HOME

[[ -n "${rvm_stored_umask:-}" ]] || export rvm_stored_umask=$(umask)
if (( ${rvm_ignore_rvmrc:=0} == 0 ))
then
  rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc")
  if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
  then rvm_rvmrc_files+=( "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" )
  fi

  for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
  do
    if [[ -f "$rvmrc" ]]
    then
      # pre-gnu
      if GREP_OPTIONS="" \command \grep '^\s*rvm .*$' "$rvmrc" >/dev/null 2>&1
      then
        printf "%b" "
Error:
        $rvmrc is for rvm settings only.
        rvm CLI may NOT be called from within $rvmrc.
        Skipping the loading of $rvmrc"
        return 1
      else
        source "$rvmrc"
      fi
    fi
  done
  unset rvm_rvmrc_files
fi

# duplication marker jdgkjnfnkjdngjkfnd4fd
# detect rvm_path if not set
if [[ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ]]
then
  if [[ -n "${BASH_SOURCE:-$_}" && -f "${BASH_SOURCE:-$_}" ]]
  then
    rvm_path="${BASH_SOURCE:-$_}"
    rvm_path="$( \command \cd "${rvm_path%/scripts/rvm}">/dev/null; pwd )"
    rvm_prefix=$( dirname $rvm_path )
  elif (( UID == 0 ))
  then
    if (( ${rvm_user_install_flag:-0} == 0 ))
    then
      rvm_prefix="/usr/local"
      rvm_path="${rvm_prefix}/rvm"
    else
      rvm_prefix="$HOME"
      rvm_path="${rvm_prefix}/.rvm"
    fi
  else
    if [[ -d "$HOME/.rvm" && -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]
    then
      rvm_prefix="$HOME"
      rvm_path="${rvm_prefix}/.rvm"
    else
      rvm_prefix="/usr/local"
      rvm_path="${rvm_prefix}/rvm"
    fi
  fi
else
  # remove trailing slashes, btw. %%/ <- does not work as expected
  rvm_path="${rvm_path%%+(\/)}"
fi

# guess rvm_prefix if not set
if [[ -z "${rvm_prefix}" ]]
then
  rvm_prefix=$( dirname $rvm_path )
fi

# duplication marker kkdfkgnjfndgjkndfjkgnkfjdgn
case "$rvm_path" in
  (/usr/local/rvm)         rvm_user_install_flag=0 ;;
  ($HOME/*|/${USER// /_}*) rvm_user_install_flag=1 ;;
  (*)                      rvm_user_install_flag=0 ;;
esac

export rvm_loaded_flag
if [[ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" || -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]] &&
  typeset -f rvm >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  rvm_loaded_flag=1
else
  rvm_loaded_flag=0
fi

if
  (( ${rvm_loaded_flag:=0} == 0 )) || (( ${rvm_reload_flag:=0} == 1 ))
then
  if
    [[ -n "${rvm_path}" && -d "$rvm_path" ]]
  then
    true ${rvm_scripts_path:="$rvm_path/scripts"}

    if
      [[ ! -f "$rvm_scripts_path/base" ]]
    then
      printf "%b" "WARNING:
      Could not source '$rvm_scripts_path/base' as file does not exist.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.\n"
    elif
      ! source "$rvm_scripts_path/base"
    then
      printf "%b" "WARNING:
      Errors sourcing '$rvm_scripts_path/base'.
      RVM will likely not work as expected.\n"
    else
      __rvm_ensure_is_a_function
      __rvm_setup

      export rvm_version
      rvm_version="$(\command \cat "$rvm_path/VERSION") ($(\command \cat "$rvm_path/RELEASE" 2>/dev/null))"

      alias rvm-restart="rvm_reload_flag=1 source '${rvm_scripts_path:-${rvm_path}/scripts}/rvm'"

      # Try to load RVM ruby if none loaded yet
      __path_to_ruby="$( builtin command -v ruby 2>/dev/null || true )"
      if
        [[ -z "${__path_to_ruby}" ]] ||
        [[ "${__path_to_ruby}" != "${rvm_path}"* ]] ||
        [[ "${__path_to_ruby}" == "${rvm_path}/bin/ruby" ]]
      then
        if [[ -s "$rvm_path/environments/default" ]]
        then source "$rvm_path/environments/default"
        fi
        if
          [[ ${rvm_project_rvmrc:-1} -gt 0 ]] &&
          ! __function_on_stack __rvm_project_rvmrc
        then
          # Reload the rvmrc, use promptless ensuring shell processes does not
          # prompt if .rvmrc trust value is not stored, revert to default on fail
          if
            rvm_current_rvmrc=""
            rvm_project_rvmrc_default=2 rvm_promptless=1 __rvm_project_rvmrc
          then
            rvm_hook=after_cd
            source "${rvm_scripts_path:-${rvm_path}/scripts}/hook"
          fi
        fi
      fi
      unset __path_to_ruby

      # Makes sure rvm_bin_path is in PATH atleast once.
      [[ ":${PATH}:" == *":${rvm_bin_path}:"* ]] || PATH="$PATH:${rvm_bin_path}"

      if
        (( ${rvm_reload_flag:=0} == 1 ))
      then
        [[ "${rvm_auto_reload_flag:-0}" == 2 ]] || printf "%b" 'RVM reloaded!\n'
        # make sure we clean env on reload
        __rvm_env_loaded=1
        unset __rvm_project_rvmrc_lock
      fi

      rvm_loaded_flag=1
      __rvm_teardown
    fi
  else
    printf "%b" "\n\$rvm_path ($rvm_path) does not exist."
  fi
  unset rvm_prefix_needs_trailing_slash rvm_gems_cache_path rvm_gems_path rvm_project_rvmrc_default rvm_gemset_separator rvm_reload_flag
fi
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Would you `cat $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and post it here?

Comment: Done, do you think there is something wrong there ?

Comment: Wait. Are you sure you use `bash`? Because it looks like you use `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh`/`presto`. What `ps -p $$` prints out?

Comment: You are right,
    PID TTY           TIME CMD
    3088 ttys000    0:00.23 -zsh

Comment: This message came from inaccurate _terminal theme_. I bet you use `oh-my-zsh`, so try to switch the theme as specified here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes — I’m sorry, but I can’t help a lot with this being blind about your current setup :)